# Is it possible to call Google Cloud Build via API with cloudbuild.yaml in source repo

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I have an Cloud Build trigger that is set up to fetch a specific branch from a remote repository and use the `cloudbuild .yaml` file from it to run the build. I need to do the same programatically via an API call and the only way I can see this happening is with an API call here: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds/create.

By looking at the required request body which is of type `Build` https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Build it seems that while I can provide the source repository (branch, commit or tag) I'm not sure how to provide the path to `cloudbuild.yaml` which in this case really needs to sit with the repo source code. Also it seems a `steps` param is required which actually has to be the steps from the cloudbuild file.

Is there any way that I can create a build using the same resources that I would otherwise set up in a cloud trigger (path to (`cloudbuild.yaml` instead of the steps to which I don't have access to in this case)?